# SD card detect in SPI mode

Tags: spi, memory, sd, detection, flash-memories

Just wondering if it is possible to detect the presence of an SD card when it is being used in SPI Mode?

[image]

It would appear that the card detect/data 3 pin (CD/DAT3) is used as a chip select (CS) pin when in SPI mode.

If this is true, then how does one detect the presence of an SD card being used in SPI mode?

Comment: The "card presense" pin is usually a NC switched contact in the (micro)sd cards socket, and not on the card itself.

Answer (score 3):

Just realized that some microSD card holders have a "hidden and un-numbered" pin called "card detect" that gets shorted to ground when a card is inserted.  See picture below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The micro sd-card socket has more than 8 pins. 
At least 2 extra pins for write protection & insertion detect.

As shown in the below picture, the insertion detect pin is grounded through mechanical means when the SD card is inserted into the slot. [image]